# Good Web Server/Servlet Container for Clojure Web Apps?

Tags: java, tomcat, clojure, jetty

I am looking for a good production web server/servlet container for my compojure web appliction. What are the pros and cons of using Jetty or Tomcat or other server for a Clojure web app using compojure? Is there any good documentation for using a web server with Clojure for production, or tools?

I would prefer a web server that is flexible, easy to configure and has good documentation on how to configure and use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not yet a pure Clojure Webserver, but I heard that people at Apache were working on something like that. On the meanwhile I have some links I found useful myself.

A commentary on Apache + Jetty: http://briancarper.net/blog/510/deploying-clojure-websites

Take a look at this for implementing your own webserver via servlets: [Clojure web application - where do I start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464071/clojure-web-application-where-do-i-start)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already have your own infrastructure to run on, you might consider Heroku, which supports Clojure. See their tutorial [Getting Started With Clojure on Heroku/Cedar](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure). It's free to start and very easy to scale.

Answer (score 0):

Chas Emerick has a rather old blog post + slides on doing [continous integration on webapps](http://cemerick.com/2010/11/02/continuous-deployment-of-clojure-web-applications/) right (Heroku, Pallet, War-file or whatever nescessary to NOT roll your own solution).