# What Web Server/Servlet Container Do You Use For Clojure Web Apps?

Tags: clojure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Web Server/Servlet Container for Clojure Web Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211640/good-web-server-servlet-container-for-clojure-web-apps)

I'm looking around to decide what web server to use for my clojure web app and am interested in what and how others are deploying their Clojure apps to web servers, especially production web servers.